# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una ordenación en una criteria de hibernate por un campo de un join de otro join?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Tengo una consulta en BBDD con unas criterias de hibernate que devuelve una lista de objetos. El objeto (servicio) tiene aparte de unos atributos otra clase (sección) con otros atributos dentro y a su vez otra clase más dentro (entidad). Dichos campos están asociados en BBDD por unos ids.
La tabla servicio contiene un id de sección y sección un id de entidad.
¿Cómo podría hacer para que la consulta de criteria me devuelva una lista ordenada por el campo código de la entidad?

Las clases que tengo son: (sólo escribiré los campos, y las relaciones):

ServicioEntity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ServicioPresupuesto")
    @Audited
    public class ServicioPresupuestoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String descripcionLarga;
    private String descripcionLargaCastellano;
    private String centro;
    private Integer numeroOficina;
    private Integer codigoOrganoEjecutor;
    private Integer codigoOrganoTeseo;
    private Integer orden;
    private String padre;
    private boolean esUltimo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "seccion_id")
    private SeccionPresupuestoEntity seccion;
```

SeccionEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SeccionPresupuesto")
@Audited
public class SeccionPresupuestoEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String codigo;
private String descripcion;
private String descripcionLarga;
private String descripcionLargaCastellano;
private String centro;
private Integer numeroOficina;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "entidad_id")
private EntidadPresupuestoEntity entidad;
```

EntidadEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntidadPresupuesto")
@Audited
public class EntidadPresupuestoEntity {

public EntidadPresupuestoEntity() {
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String codigo;
private Integer orden;
private String descripcion;
private String descripcionLarga;
private String descripcionLargaCastellano;
private String acronimo;
private String nif;
private Integer codigoAmbitoGestionPersonal;
private String codigoTipoEntidad;
```

La consulta criteria de hibernate sería la siguiente:

```
@Override
public List<ServicioPresupuestoEntity> 
buscarServicioPresupuestoEntities(final OrganicaPresupuestoFiltro filtro) {
    final Criteria cri = 
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ServicioPresupuestoEntity.class, 
"servicio");

    if (filtro.getIdServicio() != null) {
        cri.add(Restrictions.eq("id", filtro.getIdServicio()));
    }

    final Criteria criSeccion = cri.createCriteria("seccion");
    final Criteria criEntidad = criSeccion.createCriteria("entidad");

    if (filtro.getPresupuesto() != null && filtro.getPresupuesto().getId() != null) {
        criEntidad.add(Restrictions.eq("presupuesto_id", filtro.getPresupuesto().getId()));
    }
    if (filtro.getIdEntidad() != null) {
        criEntidad.add(Restrictions.eq("id", filtro.getIdEntidad()));
    }
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoEntidad())) {
        criEntidad.add(Restrictions.eq("codigo", filtro.getCodigoEntidad()));
    }
    if (filtro.getIdSeccion() != null) {
        criSeccion.add(Restrictions.eq("id", filtro.getIdSeccion()));
    }
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoSeccion())) {
        criSeccion.add(Restrictions.eq("codigo", filtro.getCodigoSeccion()));
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoServicio())) {
        cri.add(Restrictions.eq("codigo", filtro.getCodigoServicio()));
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoServicioLike())
            || !StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getDescripcionServicio())) {

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoServicioLike())
                && !StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getDescripcionServicio())) {
            cri.add(Restrictions.or(
                    Restrictions.ilike("codigo", filtro.getCodigoServicioLike(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE),
                    Restrictions.ilike("descripcion", filtro.getDescripcionServicio(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
        } else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getCodigoSeccionLike())) {
            cri.add(Restrictions.ilike("codigo", filtro.getCodigoSeccionLike(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        } else {
            cri.add(Restrictions.ilike("descripcion", filtro.getDescripcionSeccion(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        }
    }

    cri.addOrder(Order.asc("orden"));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<ServicioPresupuestoEntity> servicios = cri.list();

    return servicios;
}
```

La consulta devuelve todo lo que tiene que devolver, sólo me falta la ordenación, tiene una por el campo orden de servicio pero la querría por el campo código de la entidad. Busqué por aquí pero no encontré una respuesta así que espero que no se haya formulado la pregunta antes.
Muchas gracias de antemano y buen día.

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar el campo por la entidad crear un alias de la con la entidad que va a utilizar y luego realizar el Order.asc

```
cri.createAlias("entidad.codigo", "codigoEntidad");
cri.addOrder(Order.asc("codigoEntidad.value"));
```

Algo así podría ayudar